# Nested Set block iteration and Range in Lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Hoping someone would have solved this.,

The object Structure I have a object structure similar to

Main Object is Student, student gets some letters

```
 public class LetterRange {
    private Date letterStartDate;
    private Date letterEndDate;

    public Date getLetterStartDate() {
        return letterStartDate;
    }

    public void setLetterStartDate(Date letterStartDate) {
        this.letterStartDate = letterStartDate;
    }

    public Date getLetterEndDate() {
        return letterEndDate;
    }

    public void setLetterEndDate(Date letterEndDate) {
        this.letterEndDate = letterEndDate;
    }
}

public class Letters {
    private String letterName;
    private Set<LetterRange> letterRangeSet;

    public String getLetterName() {
        return letterName;
    }

    public void setLetterName(String letterName) {
        this.letterName = letterName;
    }

    public Set<LetterRange> getLetterRangeSet() {
        return letterRangeSet;
    }

    public void setLetterRangeSet(Set<LetterRange> letterRangeSet) {
        this.letterRangeSet = letterRangeSet;
    }
}

public class Student {
    private String name;
    Set<Letters> lettersSet;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Letters> getLettersSet() {
        return lettersSet;
    }

    public void setLettersSet(Set<Letters> lettersSet) {
        this.lettersSet = lettersSet;
    }
}
public class StudentRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    Student one = new Student();
    Student two= new Student();
    Student three= new Student();
    one.setName("John");

    Letters johnLetter1 = new Letters();
    johnLetter1.setLetterName("Kudos");

    Letters janeLetter = new Letters();
    janeLetter.setLetterName("Jane Kudos");

    Letters otherJaneLetter = new Letters();
    otherJaneLetter.setLetterName("Other Jane letter");


    one.setLettersSet(new HashSet<Letters>() {{
        add(johnLetter1);
        add(janeLetter);
        add(otherJaneLetter);
    }});

    two.setLettersSet(new HashSet<Letters>(){{
        add(johnLetter1);
        add(janeLetter);
    }});

    LetterRange johnLetter1Range = new LetterRange();
    johnLetter1Range.setLetterStartDate(new Date());
    johnLetter1Range.setLetterEndDate(new Date());

    LetterRange johnLetter2Range = new LetterRange();
    johnLetter1Range.setLetterStartDate(DateTime.now().plus(10).toDate());
    johnLetter1Range.setLetterEndDate(DateTime.now().plus(10).toDate());

    johnLetter1.setLetterRangeSet(new HashSet<LetterRange>() {{
        add(johnLetter1Range);
        add(johnLetter2Range);
    }});

    studentList.add(one);

    Set dataSet = studentList.stream().flatMap(student -> student.getLettersSet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());


   Letters dataMap= studentList.stream().flatMap(student -> student.getLettersSet().stream()).filter(letters -> StringUtils.contains(letters.getLetterName(),"Jane")).findAny().orElseThrow(
        NoSuchElementException::new);
    System.out.println(dataMap);
    System.out.println(studentList.stream().flatMap(student -> student.getLettersSet().stream()).filter(letters -> StringUtils.contains(letters.getLetterName(),"Jane")).collect(Collectors.toSet()));
    Assert.assertTrue(dataSet.size() == 1);
    }
}
```

Am stuck where am trying to get a lambda to return me all the Students (outermost object list) based on the filter condition. I know we can iterate the plain old way, but am trying to see if there a lambda that can help me it. TIA.

Comment: Changes the psuedo a bit., thanks

Comment: Let me copy paste the code., in few. update it.

Comment: Did you actually copy-paste this code? There are multiple glaring errors in the code! (e.g., "Class" instead of "class")

Comment: Ty., have the actual code now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is 2 flat maps:

```
Set<LetterRange> rangeOfLetters = studentList.stream()
        .flatMap(x -> x.letterSet.stream())
        .flatMap(x -> x.letterRanges.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

A flat map operation can turn this:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

into this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Your data structure is like this:

```
[
    <
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange}
    >,
    <
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange}
    >,
    <
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange}
    >
]
```

The `[]` represents the outermost set. The `<>` represents student objects and the `{}` represents letters objects.

The first flat map maps turns the data into this:

```
    [
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange},
        {LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange}
    ]
```

And the second flat map turns the data into:

```
[
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange,
    LetterRange, LetterRange, LetterRange
]
```

Comment: Beaten by 39 seconds

Answer (score 4):

A way to tackle this is to use intermediate variables and see what you get at each stage.

```
Stream<Student> studentStream = studentList.stream();
```

... is a good start. You can work out for yourself the type of `studentStream`, and it's good to be able to. But your IDE will tell you if it's wrong - and you can even get the IDE to put the right type in for you.

You know you need `flatMap` because you know you're flattening a nested structure. And the function you pass to `flatMap` must consume a `Student` and return a `Stream<?>`, so your options are limited:

```
Stream<Letters> lettersStream = studentStream.flatMap(
    stu -> stu.getLettersSet().stream());
```

Getting closer to your aim from a `Stream<Letters>` is basically the same train of thought as before:

```
Stream<LetterRange> letterRangeStream = lettersStream.flatMap(
     ls -> ls.getLetterRangeSet().stream());
```

... and now you have what you want; you just need to collect it into a `List`:

```
List<LetterRange> letterRanges = letterRangeStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You may choose to leave it like that:

```
    Stream<Student> studentStream = studentList.stream();
    Stream<Letters> lettersStream = studentStream.flatMap(
          stu -> stu.getLettersSet().stream());
    Stream<LetterRange> letterRangeStream = lettersStream.flatMap(
          ls -> ls.getLetterRangeSet().stream());
    List<LetterRange> letterRanges = letterRangeStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

... which is fine -- the JRE will optimise away the intermediate variables anyway. But if you want to, you can inline them (by hand, or with your IDE's "inline variable" refactoring tool) to:

```
List<LetterRange> letterRanges = studentList.stream()
   .flatMap(stu -> stu.getLettersSet().stream())
   .flatMap(ls -> ls.getLetterRangeSet().stream())
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I missed the part of doing flat maps for flattening it out more. I was got stuck trying to retune an inline code to keep it simple. Thanks!